# Best way to find a hash that contains a key, in an array of hashes in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Say we have

```
[{:name=>"Joe", :age => 15},{:name=>"Josh", :age => 83},{:name=>"Jim", :age => 1203}]
```

What is the best way way to get the hash where the name is "Joe"? To return `{:name=>"Joe", :age=>15}`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`array.select` will return an array of values (even if there is only one match):

```
my_array.select { |item| item[:name] == "Joe" }
# => [{:name => "Joe", :age => 15}]
```

You can use Enumerable's `find` method instead to return the first instance (as a hash):

```
my_array.find { |item| item[:name] == "Joe" }
# => {:name => "Joe", :age => 15}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
array.select { |e| e[:name] == 'Joe' }.first
```

Comment: ".detect" does the same as ".select().first"

Answer (score 1):

If this is an operation you need to perform frequently, then store the set of hashes as a hash of hashes, with the value for the `name` key as the key to each hash. That way you can look up your hashes in `O(1)` time.